# How do I add a HeaderRenderer to react-data-grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, formatting, react-data-grid

I'm working with [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid), which for the most part is exactly what I need. However, I have about 70 columns that need to be editable, but whose content is actual quite narrow. I'd like to display the headers vertically.

I've read through the docs as they are, and I think I need to add a headerRenderer. I also *think* that signature for that is `( column, rowType )`, but the docs are a little hazy on that.

I've tried:

```
....

const rotatedHeaderRenderer = (column, rowType) => {
  return <span className="rotate">{column.name}</span>;
};

....

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { rows };

  onGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const rows = state.rows.slice();
      for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
        rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...updated };
      }
      return { rows };
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactDataGrid
          columns={columns}
          rowGetter={i => this.state.rows[i]}
          rowsCount={3}
          headerRowHeight={123}
          onGridRowsUpdated={this.onGridRowsUpdated}
          enableCellSelect={true}
          headerRenderer={rotatedHeaderRenderer}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but I get nothing back (although the component does render). I've tried dropping the `.name`, and yes it tells me that `column` is an object.

What am I doing wrong? Is there somewhere else I should be looking in the docs?

Also: If I need to do it on a column-by-column basis, I've happy to change the column definition and somehow apply the renderer in there?

---

### Edit

Found a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Luis-Palacios/react-data-grid-header-renderer-test/blob/master/src/App.js) that helped a little, although there are some obvious errors in there...

I can rotate the contents of the header cells themselves, by changing the column definitions and applying a header renderer to every column in turn:

```
function VericalHeader(item) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        transform: "rotate(-90deg)",
        filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)"
      }}
    >
      {item.column.name}
    </div>
  );
}

....

const columns = [

  ....

  {
    key: "base_unit_of_measure",
    name: "Base Unit of Measure",
    headerRenderer: VericalHeader
  },

  ....

  ];
```

And the result turns out something like this...

```html
<div 
    class="react-grid-HeaderCell" 
    style="width: 80px;
    left: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: none;"
>
    <div style="transform: rotate(-90deg);">
        Base Unit of Measure
    </div>
</div>
```

... which sort of works, but the text now won't align left (i.e. to the visual bottom of the `div.react-grid-HeaderCell`). All this tells me sadly that I'm actually going to have to subclass the `react-data-grid/src/Header.tsx` component, which will only require me to learn Typescript ;-)

Hey ho...

Comment: Im not sure if you're looking to expand columns or get headers vertically , but I've found this doc where you can resize the columns, hope this helps 
https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/column-resizing
You can also get few more examples in this

Comment: No, I really, really want to rotate the header titles ;-) I already know the column widths to set